# Differentiate Between free/trial (developers, sandbox) orgs vs Production Orgs?

Tags: apex, soql, admin

Using the `Organization` object we can differentiate between Production or Sandbox orgs using `IsSandbox`. Is there any programatic way to differentiate between a Developer Free Org vs a typical Production Org?

I see there is `Organization.OrganizationType` with following values, but it holds value as followings

- Enterprise Edition (dev org created from partner portal)
- Developer Edition (typical dev org)

Is there any easy and deterministic way to differentiate between Production and Developer Edition orgs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The various values for Organization Type are:

- Team Edition
- Professional Edition
- Enterprise Edition
- Developer Edition
- Personal Edition
- Unlimited Edition
- Contact Manager
- Edition Base Edition

Here is a simple logic to tell whether the org is a true production or developer org.

1. If the OrganizationType **equal** to Developer Edition, it is not production definitely.
2. If the OrganizationType equal to Enterprise Edition OR Unlimited Edition Professional Edition and has TrialExpirationDate, then it is not production.
3. Organization.IsSandbox = True, then it is not production, but a sandbox org.

We can find this using the following query:

```
SELECT
  Id, Name, InstanceName, IsSandbox, OrganizationType, TrialExpirationDate
FROM Organization
```